# How does one create a TranslationServiceClient using a json as authentication?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

Hello and thanks for reading my question.

I'm working on transitioning some code from `Google.Cloud.Translation.V2` to `Google.Cloud.Translate.V3` because we need to make use of the api advanced features.
We are using a `TranslationClient` to get us the translations (from the V2 library) but we need to instead use the [`TranslationServiceClient`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3/api/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3.TranslationServiceClientBuilder.html) (from the V3 library.)
I'm having trouble instantiating a `TranslationServiceClient` with our credentials. The way to do it in V2 is straightforward:

```
TranslationClient.Create(GoogleCredential.FromJson("{\"the credentials\"}"));
```

From reading the documentation it is clear to me that to create a `TranslationServiceClient` without the default settings you need to use a [`TranslationServiceClientBuilder`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3/api/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3.TranslationServiceClientBuilder.html) and give that the credentials.  I couldn't find any examples, all of the code snippets use `TranslationServiceClient.Create()` which doesn't allow for any arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the goal is to create a `TranslationServiceClient` using a json as authentication, one way to do this is as follows:

```
TranslationServiceClient client = new TranslationServiceClientBuilder {
                        JsonCredentials = "{\"the credentials\"}"
                    }.Build()
```

More info at https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_the_path_to_the_service_account_key_in_code

Comment: how do I feed API key to that beast?

Answer (score 0):

Positive attitude / embracing change:

Problem solving / evolving:

```
const GOOGLE_TRANSLATE = new GoogleTranslate(
  {
    projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    credentials: {
      client_email: auth.client_email,
      private_key: auth.private_key,
    }
  },
)
```